# Kill second activity of second package from first activity of first package in android

Tags: android

I have two packages:

- com.surveydemo with SurveyDemoActivity; and
- com.surveydemo.DroidPHP with HomeActivity.

I made one quit button in SurveyDemoActivity and after click on this button it prompted "Do you really want to quit" with two options:

- "return"
- "quit"

When I click on return it goes to SurveyDemoActivity and if I click on quit nothing happens.

If I click on quit button, I want to finish both activity("SurveyDemoActivity" & "HomeActivity"). How can I do this please?

Any help appreciated.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Activities within same app is not dependent on packages

Answer (score 0):

You should start `SurveyDemoActivity` as `StartActivityForResult` so that if user taps on `quit` and cofirm it you can set corresponding result that will call `finish` in `HomeActivity` also .

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1) Define `RC_SURVEY = 3` and `RESULT_QUIT = 33`

2) Start SurveyDemoActivity using `startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SURVEY);`

3) On "quit", close SurveyDemoActivity:

```
    setResult(RESULT_QUIT);
    finish();
```

4) In onActivityResult of HomeActivity check result and close parent activity:

```
    if(request == RC_SURVEY && result == RESULT_QUIT)
        finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a BroadcastReceiver, once a user click the quit button, send a broadcast to kill the activity.

in the first Activity:

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        finish();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(MainActivity2.CUSTOM_INTENT);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

and in the 2nd Activity:

```
    public static final String CUSTOM_INTENT = "custom.intent.action.KILL";

    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setAction(CUSTOM_INTENT);
            sendBroadcast(i);
        }
    });
```